# PHP - MYSQL ZingChart Time is 7 hours ahead

Tags: php, mysql, time, charts, zingchart

ZingChart:

[image]

MySQL Table:

[image]

How do i fix this? The time in the graph doesn't match the time in the database.
Any help is appreciated.

Here's the script of the graph:

```html
    <script>
      <?php
        
        $query = "SELECT date,temperature from tb_temperature where date >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)";

        $date = []; // Array to hold our date values
        $series = []; // Array to hold our series values

       $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usernm, $passwd, $dbname, $port);
        if($mysqli->connect_error) {
          die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ')' . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
          while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){

            array_push($date, $row[0]);
            array_push($series, $row[1]);
          }

    
          foreach ($date as &$value){
            $value = strtotime( $value ) * 1000;
          }

   
          $result->close();
        }
      ?>
   
      var dateValues = [<?php echo join($date, ',') ?>];
      var seriesValues = [<?php echo join($series, ',') ?>];
      <?php

        $mysqli->close(); 
      
      ?>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely the `utc` offset. Whatever timezone the machine you're running this on, that's the timezone it is in. You can change this with setting `utc:true` and setting the `timezone:7` to set the offset.

You can inspect lines 3 & 4 of the `JS` tab in this
[demo](http://codepen.io/zingchart/pen/QGWYmy).